# Detect Large and Small font sizes of Tesseract OCR Java implementation

Tags: java, fonts, ocr, tesseract, detect

Is it possible to  **OCR** a picture and identify different *sizes of fonts in the picture* using Tesseract OCR. If yes, do I need to use any other 3rd party library or can I use pure Java. For an example,

> I want to detect the headline and the content of a newspaper by using the font size.

Any help regarding this matter would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ResultIterator.WordFontAttributes API method ([example in Java using Tess4J](http://sourceforge.net/p/tess4j/code/HEAD/tree/Tess4J_3/trunk/test/net/sourceforge/tess4j/TessAPI1Test.java)) to retrieve font information, including font name and size, of the recognized text.

Answer (score 0):

The hOCR output of Tesseract includes the bounding boxes of lines and words which can be used to determine size and it can be configured to also include the point size of the font in the output by turning on the `hocr_font_info` config variable.